# advanced search falling behind

Tags: bug, search

Is the advanced search falling behind in the question it holds, or is it me doing something wrong? I have bookmarked the following search (the newest tab)

```
[c++] -[qt] answers:0 closed:no duplicate:no
```

as

```
http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[c%2b%2b]%20-[qt]%20answers%3a0%20closed%3ano%20duplicate%3ano
```

and the newest results I am seeing are from june 2nd (on various browsers if that is somehow relevant)

Comment: I was about to report this too.